# Given $a,b \in S^n$, then there exists an isometry $f: S^n \rightarrow S^n$ such that $f(a) = b$

Tags: linear-algebra, metric-spaces, rotations, reflection, isometry

$S^n = \{x\in \mathbb{R}^{n+1} : \|x\| = 1\}.$

I am using this definition: isometry is a surjective function $f:M \rightarrow N$ between two metric spaces $(M,d)$ and $(N,\rho)$ such that
$$\rho (f(x),f(y)) = d(x,y) \quad \forall  x,y \in M $$

**My attempt:**

Let $v  = a-b$.
Since $\|a\| = \|b\|$, the following  Householder transformation maps 
$a$ to $b$ and vice versa:

$$H = I -2\frac{v v^t}{v^tv}$$
We have:
$$H \cdot a= a -2\frac{(a-b) (a-b)^ta}{(a-b)^t(a-b)} = 
\frac{a(a-b)^t(a-b)-2(a-b)(a-b)^ta}{(a-b)^t(a-b)}$$
$$= \frac{aa^ta - aa^tb - ab^ta + ab^tb-2aa^ta + 2ab^ta+2ba^ta -2bb^ta}{(a-b)^t(a-b)}$$
$$= \frac{aa^ta - 2ab^ta + ab^tb-2aa^ta + 2ab^ta+2ba^ta -2bb^ta}{(a-b)^t(a-b)}$$
$$= \frac{- 2ab^ta + 2ab^ta+2ba^ta -2bb^ta}{(a-b)^t(a-b)} =
\frac{2ba^ta -2bb^ta}{(a-b)^t(a-b)}= 
\frac{ba^ta +  bb^tb -2bb^ta}{(a-b)^t(a-b)}$$
$$= \frac{b(a-b)^t(a-b)}{(a-b)^t(a-b)} = b$$

Householder transformations are orthogonal, then $H$ preserves norm and distance. Thus $f(x) = H\cdot x$ maps $S^n$ to $S^n$ and preserves distance.
If $f$ is a  surjective function, then $f$ is an isometry.

My questions are:

**1)** Is the function $H: S^n \rightarrow S^n$ surjective ?

**2)** Is it possible to solve this problem using rotations instead of reflections?
How could I find a rotation matrix $Q$ such that $Q\cdot a = b$?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since $H^t$ is also orthogonal then $w=H^tv\in S^n$ for every $v\in S^n$ then $Hw=HH^tv=v$. Thus $H:S^n\rightarrow S^n$ is surjective. The answer to the second question is YES. Consider the plane spanned by $a,b$ and the linear transformation that rotates $a$ to $b$ and restricted to the orthogonal complement of this plane is the identity.

Answer (score 0):

1) The Householder transform is a reflection across the hyperplane perpendicular to $v$ and as such it is its own inverse:  $H^{-1} = H$.

2) Consider an auxiliary $c$, then $H_1$ taking $a$ to $c$ and $H_2$ taking $c$ to $b$. Then $H_2 \circ H_1$ is a rotation taking $a$ to $b$.